# JavaScript Object definition return an String instead the entire object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I wonder if we can define an Object like it is location object... example:

```
var a = {a:'asd', b:someFunction};
console.log( a );
//Desired: 'asd'
//Actual: Object {a,b}...

console.log( a.a );
//> 'asd'
console.log( a.b );
//> function() ...
```

This behavior works with [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

At this point the only way I can emulate this is scaping via toStrin

```
a.toString = ()-> return a.a
console.log( ''+a )
//> 'asd'
```

So, exist a clean way to achieve this within our code or this behavior just work with system variables?

Comment: `console.log( a );
//Return     > 'asd'` ? Are you sure ?

Comment: that doesn't make alot of sense.

Comment: Your question is not correct. It logs this `Object {a: "asd"}`

Comment: He wants it to print `'asd'` instead of `Object {...}`, if I read it correctly. I've made an edit, please revert it if you disagree with it @DanielFox.

Comment: Don't think you can.

Even a = new String('asd') doesn't print asd.
In fact, browsers may suddenly decide to print your objects in the console in a different way later if they wanted to.

Comment: `console.log(window.location)` shows the location object (at least in Chrome), not what you describe. What is the actual use case? If you want it for debugging purposes, write your own debugging function that calls the toString method.

Comment: He asks about `location` object. But `console.log(location)` prints `Object{...}`. Left side `location = ...` works exactly as `location.href = ...`

Comment: @Juhana ```console.log(window.location)``` returns ```http://stackoverflow.com/que.....``` instead of
```Object:{
      url:function,href:function,protocol:function... and so on}```

Comment: `console.log(location);` for me returns `Location → file:///C:/test/test.html`. And Location is clickable to allow me to access the location object. [In Firefox]. JavaScript does not operate quite like Java, for obvious reasons. I personally do not see the use case for this in JavaScript. An explicit call or use of toString() should be fine.

Comment: Like Alex says, the console isn't standardized so the output differs depending on the browser and even browser version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that i find was to use the String object:

```
var a = new String('asd');
a.b = someUsefullFunction
```

But has @jason-fetterly says the output heavily depends with the browser you are test so in the for stability concerns this is not viable in javaScript.

Also if you want this has I say in the beginning and other points use toString overide

```
a.toString = function(){return a.a};
console.log( ''+a )
```

The theoretical part of this question late I learn is (Object/Function) overload, factible in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can override toString() so that whenever you use the object in the context of a string, you get a.a value.  This doesn't change console.log(a) however.  If this doesn't help, perhaps you should edit your quest and provide more information about your use case.

```
var a = {
  a: 'asd',
  b: function someFunction() {}
};
a.toString = function() {
  return this.a;
};

alert(a);
// Dialog with 'asd'

console.log('Value of a: '+a);
// Console prints 'Value of a: asd'

console.log(a);
// Exact print depends on browser, but full object details will likely be shown
```